# Python: Replicate rows in a dataframe by number of items in a column

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a table like this [image]

I would like to replicate each row by the number of items in the 'Brand' column, and in the result table brand column would only have a single item, like this [image]

How to achieve this in Python? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html#pandas-dataframe-explode):

```py
df = df.assign(Brand=df.Brand.str.split(",")).explode("Brand")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        Date Brand    Cost
0  6/23/2021     A  $100.0
0  6/23/2021     B  $100.0
0  6/23/2021     C  $100.0
1  6/23/2021     A  $200.0
1  6/23/2021     B  $200.0
2  6/23/2021     A  $300.0
2  6/23/2021     B  $300.0
2  6/23/2021     C  $300.0
2  6/23/2021     D  $300.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this clear simple solve!